# Clone development environment on an office server to use locally

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

Situation:
As a developer I'd like to "clone" our development environment (on an office server) so we can use it locally (for example when no/limited internet access is available). We've decided to give Vagrant a try.

What did I do?
First I used [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) to create a basic config including nginx, php (incl modules), composer, git, memcached etc. You can find my config [here](http://pastebin.com/e3LBJjnx). I also added a nginx vhost for our `website.dev`. This is where I run into the first problem.

We use a few additional config settings to the location block. A `rewrite`, a `fastcgi_pass` and a `include`. This is not available so I searched a lot online and I found out I could use the following statement (was more a try/fail/retry).

```
location_cfg_append:
  { rewrite: ".* /dispatch.php break", include: "fastcgi-params.conf", fastcgi_pass: "127.0.0.1:9000" }
```

First question: 
This does work, however is this the way to do this? I'm not sure if I should be editing this config file (the file generated by PuPHPet) directly.

Second question:
How should I 'upload' the `fastcgi-params.conf` file I want to include? I did not find a way to do this in the `config.yaml` but there is a way to run some scripts. For now I've added a `echo [contents] > /etc/nginx/fastcgi-params.conf` that does work. However...

Third question:
When the VM is provisioned the nginx config is created. When that is done nginx is restarted. However at that moment the `fastcgi-params.conf` file does not exist yet (this is created AFTER the provisioning).

When nginx reloads this will fail, trigger an error and the machine can not finish the provision sequence (so it will never create the config file).

I can create this file on the next boot (and then nginx will work) but this cannot be the correct way to do this. So: how can I (before nginx 'installation') create / deploy a file to the VM? Or more generic (question 2): How can I upload a file to the VM?

If this is totally not the way to go please let me know! This are our first steps into creating a locally development machine so other/better methods are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> First question: This does work, however is this the way to do this? I'm not sure if I should be editing this config file (the file generated by PuPHPet) directly.

Yes, I encourage this.

> Second question: How should I 'upload' the fastcgi-params.conf file I want to include?

Place it inside one of your shared folders. It'll be available within the VM and you can reference it that way.

> Third question

The above answer fixes this issue.